# How to build Preview functionality before form submit in Rails ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple scaffold and I want the user to see (preview) the form data before he submits it. It looks to be fairly straight forward problem but surprisingly **I am not able to figure out how to do it**. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892017/best-way-to-create-preview-functionality-in-rails) but it looks to be somewhat dated (2010 question)

Is there any gem or jquery plugin which can simplify this preview functionality ? any suggestions on how to do it in rails 3.2.x ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what kind of "preview" you want to include - either "preview page" or "rendered fragment":

Preview page is what some services are showing: summary of all inputs shown in form of separate page with button "confirm". It doesn't require javascript or anything fancy - just click "next" on form page, see data typed just a second ago and click "confirm" or "back to edit". If this is what you require then you can do it simply by creating new controller action(preview?) which would initialize model with passed parameters(just like "create" action would, but without saving) and generate template with "preview" shown and hidden form that will be passed to "create" action after clicking "confirm". Alternatively you can simply modify "new" form so it would hide form depending on called action and show preview instead.

Second option is "render fragment" - it will live-update part of your current page via javascript. Depending on how complicated this view will be and what kind of operations you will need to do before showing template it might be good to use some javascript plugin or send request to server and obtain rendered partial. In former case you can select from very easy implementations(like [this](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_live_text_input)) up to complete solutions dedicated to it. On the other hand if you choose to render it on server then simple ajax request with all params of form should be enough to provide you with HTML output that can be put directly into DOM element.

Comment: After lots of search I found your which makes most sense except it is more abstract for my brain :) I would appreciate if you can elaborate here or on my similar situation/question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228853/rails-how-to-review-content-before-submit-save . Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about any gem which can do that.

I think showing a modal with jquery and getting data from data-elements is a simple way to go.