# Rails: How to review content before submit/save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know it is simple but I can't get my head around a solution.

It is a job board site. Lets say it's functionality similar to [this site](https://weworkremotely.com/jobs/new). When a user fill all required information and click "**To next step**" or "**Preview**", another page loads with all filled data. That page is similar to the final page when data is saved.

When user on preview page, it can go forward and submit the page (in this case it will be saved to DB). Or, click back to Edit the job.

I tried the following::

- Within `_form.html.erb` I added a preview button 
  `<%= f.submit "Preview", :name => 'preview' %>`
- Within `JobControllers` I altered create method 

  `def create
  if params[:preview]
    @job = Job.new(jobs_params)
    render 'jobs/preview'
  else
    @job.save
  end
  end`
- Created a Preview view `/jobs/preview.html.erb`

Now I have 2 problems.

1- Within my preview page, I have an edit button like so: `<%= link_to "Edit Job", edit_job_path(@job) %>`. But I have an error because I can't find `@job`. Error says: `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"jobs", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`

**SOLUTION** Changed like to `<%= link_to 'Back to edit', 'javascript:history.go(-1);' %>`

2- How I would submit and add to my DB all information on preview page?

Thank you.

Comment: Whats not working? Its going to be very difficult for anyone to help without specific code / errors / etc

Answer (score 0):

When I have to do something like this what I normally do is create a review table in my app. This table looks just like the table that is going to saving to.

When they press the "Approved" or "Save" button just populate the new table with the proper data.

I like to create a routes to handle this

```
resources :something do
  match 'move_to_something_else' => 'somethings#move_to_something_else', as: :move_to_something_else, via: :all
end
```

Now on the controller we can do the following:

```
def move_to_something_else
  @something = Something.find(params[:id])
  @something_else = SomethingElse.new
  @something_else.name = @something.name
  ....
  @something_else.save
  redirect_to something_else_path(@something_else)
end
```

Alternative you could add a state to your table with the default value of 'draft'

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :something do
  match 'published' => 'somethings#published', as: :published, via: :all
end

# Controller
def published
  @something = Something.find(params[:id])
  @something.state = 'published'
  @something.save
  redirect_to something_path(@something)
end
```

Comment: Why a separate table, much easier to just have a column called draft or something.

Comment: maybe you want to have a history of changes, that you can't just do with draft.  it also keeps the data of the new table cleaner

Comment: Well, I disagree, but I guess that's the beauty of programming. Using some gem like papertrail would be better for version history IMO.

Comment: I do like the `papertrail` gem.  and your solution would work just fine. its just the approach on the problem that we want to take :), I know that its never only 1 way and that is why if we where on the same project we would have a conversation on how to implement this

Comment: Indeed we would, I like talking about different approaches :)

Comment: same here. I know that I don't know everything and every day I learn something new :)

Answer (score 0):

Once I've given a similar task. What I've done is **to save** records, but not to publish. In my index (resource listing) action of relevant controller, I only fetch `published` records. Also show action prechecks if that record's `published` attribute is set to `true`.

What was my model/controllers looked like before

```
#model
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :active, -> { where(published: true).some_other_queries }

  self.active?
    (published && some_other_requirements)
  end
  ...
end


#controller
def index
  @books = Book.active
  ...
end

def show
  if @book.active?
    render 'show'
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

First added a secret key for previews.

```
#model
def secret
  #some custom random key generation  
  # e.g. Digest::MD5.hexdigest("#{id}_#{ENV['RAILS_SECRET']}")
end
```

Then added preview action to controller

```
def preview
  # i don't check if the record is active.
  # also added a security layer, to prevent irrelevant guys to view
  # that record
  if @book.secret == params[:secret]
    render 'show'
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

In dashboard

```
...
 = link_to "Preview", preview_book_path(book, secret: book.secret)
...
```

then added a member route

```
#routes
resources :books do
  get :preview, on: :member
end
```